# React Prop does not have value, cannot console log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to pass API data to App.js in the form of a prop. I can console log the API data so I know its coming through. When I assign it to a prop though I get ResultList.js:28 Uncaught (in promise) 
TypeError: this.props.openState is not a function. Is this the correct syntax? Sorry if this is a naive question I am very new to all this.

I have tried assigning it a few different ways but my unfamiliarity with props is getting in the way. I know the API is returning data because I can console log that out.

`````
````import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
````import zipcodes from "zipcodes";
````import SearchBar from "../../components/SearchBar/SearchBar";
````import ResultsDisplay from "../../components/ResultDisplay/ResultDisplay";
````import Nav from "../../components/Nav/Nav"
````import API from "../../API";
````import Footer from "../../components/Footer/Footer";
````import "./ResultsList.css";

````class ResultList extends React.Component {
    ````state = {
        ````openState: [],
        ````proPublica: []
    ````}
    ````onSearchSubmit = zipcode => {
        ````const data = zipcodes.lookup(zipcode);
        ````const state = data.state;
        ````const lat = data.latitude.toFixed(2);
        ````const lon = data.longitude.toFixed(2);

        ````const openStateQuery = "lat=" + lat + "&long=" + lon;

        ````API.getOpenStateData("api/v1/legislators/geo/?" + ````openStateQuery).then(OSresponse => {

            ````this.props.openState(OSresponse.data)//making the data a prop so ````we can pass it to app.js
            ````console.log("OSresponse:", OSresponse.data);
            ````console.log(this.props.openState)
        });
    }

   ```` render() {
       ```` return (
           ```` <div>
               ```` <Helmet>
                   ```` <style>{'body { background-color: #f0f0f0;}'}</style>
                ````</Helmet>
                ````<Nav />
                ````<SearchBar
                    ````onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit}
                    ````placeholder="Enter a zip code..."
                ````/>
                ````<div className="container">
                    ````<div className="results-container">
                        ````I removed this divs content for sake of brevity
                  ````  </div>
                ````</div>
                ````<Footer />
            ````</div>
        ````)
    ````}
````}

````export default ResultList;
I would expect the same response as 
console.log("OSresponse:", OSresponse.data);
`````

Comment: Did my answer make sense? If not can you provide further details?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really provided enough details or code to be able to work out what the issue is, but it sounds like you haven't passed down the correct props to this react component. You need to pass down a function from `App.js` to this file as a prop called `openState`

e.g.

```
// App.js
openState = (data) => {
  // do something with the data
  this.setState({ data })
}

render() {
  return <MyComponent openState={this.openState} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting, `TypeError: this.props.openState is not a function.`, is due to this line only,

```
this.props.openState(OSresponse.data)
```

This means you are trying to access a function from a parent component which is in your case is not present at all. Instead this is your parent component and you need to pass data from this component to your child component.

You should set the data in the state from your API response,

```
this.setState({openState:OSresponse.data})
```

Now you are ready to pass your data to child component's,

```
<AnyComponent openState={this.state.openState} />
```

In you `AnyComponent`, now you can use this data like,

```
this.props.openState
```

[Also see](https://codeburst.io/react-js-pass-data-from-components-8965d7892ca2)